# PocketWizard without cable

Tags: off-camera-flash, remote, wireless-flash, pocket-wizard

I have only used `Cowboy studio` triggers and not familiar with `PocketWizard`.
My question is if I get `PocketWizard Plus III` from what I saw on YouTube videos they were connected to the remote flash still with a cable but with `CowBoy studios` I didn't need a cable for remote flash, it was wireless, connected under the shoe of the remote flash.
Is there an option in PocketWizard that does that too? or do we always need cable? I am looking for something for my wedding photography experience I am going as a second shooter.

This picture is what I do not want to do :D

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in 2013 PocketWizard [announced](http://www.pocketwizard.com/news_events/news/hsfm3_release/) a hot shoe cable for the first time which somewhat addresses your concern. It is the HSFM3 and can be found [here](http://www.pocketwizard.com/products/cable_accessory/flash_sync_cables/hsfm3/?utm_source=Lyris&utm_medium=eBlast&utm_campaign=PocketWizard%20Newsletter%20August%202013).

PocketWizard also offers the MiniTT1 and FlexTT5 with both mount directly to the hot shoe.

I assume that the reason that PocketWizard prefers PC Sync connectivity vs Hot Shoe is that adding additional height to the hot shoe can get a bit top heavy and cumbersome especially when mounted directly on a camera vs a light stand. It may have something to do with the radios they are using, and overall design decisions as well. I think that at one time PC Sync ports were common in virtually all flash/speedlight/speedlite units, where as today they seem to be not included in lower end models.

Comment: Thanks for the info, so if I don't want to use a flash stand and want to carry around the flash with me, the picture I posted is actually normal among photographers? These are my very first experiences with remote flash and I don't have an studio so it looked a little weird.

Comment: Oh yeah, the picture that you posted is extremely common to see from a professional. Except maybe the sto-fen diffuser. I hate those things :-P But maybe I don't follow what you are trying to achieve, if you don't have a flash stand, why are you using a pocket wizard in the first place?

Comment: I have a flash stand for practicing at home in my room! ( from David Hobby starter kits) but I imagined if I go to the wedding and won't be able to haul the flash stand around, then how do photographers carry their flash and pocket wizard... so this question came to mind

Comment: I'm just saying that there isn't a point to having a pocket wizard unless the flash is off camera or you are controlling multiple cameras that I'm assuming would utilize a flash stand. If no flash stand is in the equation, one probably doesn't need a pocket wizard!

Comment: Ok got it, so I just put the flash on the camera in the wedding when I want to walk around and take pictures...thanks.  I guess I was confused after seeing this photographer photo that was holding his flash with one hand and camera in the other hand... https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/p180x540/11057310_10152991064211107_5913146603780936744_n.jpg?oh=b455b7909d92b06cab6c2abf8de905af&oe=55A0384A&__gda__=1439754588_3181fb22172d10c5fb69573d1f5261e1

Comment: Yeah you can do what he is doing in the photo but that is far from typical. It's a bit more ninja then I would recommend to anyone getting started. Especially at a wedding, normally the less flash the better. I only use flash at a wedding during the reception and any formals as I find it intrusive during the ceremony. For any candid stuff at the reception, on camera and bounced off the ceiling usually works best; in left hand pointed directly at subjects will rarely look flattering or good.